# Display localstorage in input on load

Tags: javascript, cookies, input, reload

I have a small web calculator which calculates time. My mobile browser gets rid of all data when I've minimised/closed the mobile broswer for a few minutes or on a page refresh so I've made a button which can reload all previous data and displays as text.

I want to get rid of the "Get old data" button and just have the page reload with all the values displayed in the input box as they were before the page refresh.

I've been thinking an onload event in the input box would work but as i understand this is not possible.

HTML

```
<body onload="getreload()">
<p>Please enter minutes</p>
<input type="text" id="etime">
<br>
<p>Please enter time in 24 hour format (eg. 15:00)</p>
<input type="text" id="stime">
<br>

<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<p id="finishtime">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="getreload()">Get old data</button>
<p id="finishtime2">

<p id="mintime2">
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {



function converToMinutes(s) {
    var c = s.split(':');
    return parseInt(c[0]) * 60 + parseInt(c[1]);
}

function parseTime(s) {
    var seconds = parseInt(s) % 60;
    return Math.floor(parseInt(s) / 60) + ":" + ((seconds < 10)?"0"+seconds:seconds);
}


var endTime = document.getElementById("etime").value; 
var startTime = converToMinutes(document.getElementById("stime").value);
var converted = parseTime(startTime - endTime);


document.getElementById('finishtime').innerHTML = "You will finish your break at " + converted;

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
localStorage.setItem("convertedTime", converted);
localStorage.setItem("endTimeReload", endTime);
} else {
// Sorry! No Web Storage support
}

}


function getreload()    {
var convertedTime = localStorage.getItem("convertedTime");
document.getElementById('finishtime2').innerHTML = "End of break time: " + convertedTime;


var endTimeReload = localStorage.getItem("endTimeReload");
document.getElementById('mintime2').innerHTML = "Minutes till next client: " + endTimeReload;
}
```

Comment: what error do you get. at a glance looks like it should work.

Comment: there's no error, it works great. I want to get rid of the "Get Old Data" button and just have the data load back in the input boxes on page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mostly there, but you are not restoring correctly and not saving the startTime.
Here is a fiddle with everything you need:
https://jsfiddle.net/22ej8scw/

Restore like this. (I also changed how it is saved)

```
function getreload()    {
    var startTime = localStorage.getItem("startTime");
    document.getElementById("stime").value = startTime;

    var endTimeReload = localStorage.getItem("endTimeReload");
    document.getElementById("etime").value = endTimeReload;

    if (startTime && endTimeReload)
        myFunction();
}
```

Comment: that worked great! thank you! is there anyway to clear all data?

Comment: don't worry, figured it out. small syntax error was stopping my clear function from working.

Answer (score 0):

So after you've calculated a time, you want those values to be there if you refresh the page?

When you calculate, save all the values in localstorage, then when the page loads (body element's 'onload') set the input boxes values to the corresponding localstorage ones (checking to make sure those values exist first)